# Validates presence of association with class_name is not passing test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, factory-bot, specifications

I have this model:

```
class UserFriend < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true

  belongs_to :friend, class_name: User
  validates :friend, presence: true
end
```

this factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_friend do
    association :user
    association :friend, factory: :user
  end
end
```

and this spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UserFriend do

  it "is invalid without a user" do
    expect(build(:user_friend, user: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:user)
  end

  it "is invalid without a friend" do
    expect(build(:user_friend, friend: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:friend)
  end
end
```

This the error message that I am getting:

```
rspec spec/models/user_friend_spec.rb 
.F

Failures:

  1) UserFriend is invalid without a friend
     Failure/Error: expect(build(:user_friend, friend: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:friend)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_friend_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.65806 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_friend_spec.rb:13 # UserFriend is invalid without a friend

Randomized with seed 56390
```

The test is passing correctly with the first expect (user) but is failing with the second one (friend)

**Aclaration**: I am not using HABTM association because I have other fields on model that I ommited for the example.

Answer (score 2):

In your model, use class name string instead of class constant, like this:

```
belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
```

Comment: I made the change but is not working yet. I update my question to add the spec error.

Comment: I believe your error comes from something proper to your code. When I asked 'paste the full error stack' I meant to run your spec with the `--backtrace` option, so we can see where the error comes from (you actually see which example fails, which is not enough to find the point of failure in your code)